# I'm doing phone verification for a flutter application and I want to remove the "+90" text in the number entry part. Can you help me

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

I'm doing phone verification for a flutter application and I want to remove the "+90" text in the number entry part.I am using the flutter intl_phone_number package

the code i wrote is here

```
InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                maxLength: 10,
                countries: const [
                  "TR",
                ],
                onInputValidated: (bool isPhoneNumberInputValidated) {
                  isPhoneNumberInputValidated
                      ? TextConstants.isPhoneNumberValid(state.phoneNumber)
                      : false;
                  context.read<AuthCubit>().validatePhoneNumber(
                      isPhoneNumberInputValidated:
                          isPhoneNumberInputValidated);
                },
                onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
                  if (phoneNumber.phoneNumber != null) {
                    if (phoneNumber.phoneNumber!.isNotEmpty) {
                      context.read<AuthCubit>().phoneNumberChanged(
                          phoneNumber: phoneNumber.phoneNumber!);
                    }
                  }
                },
                cursorColor: ColorConstants.blackColor,
                formatInput: false,
                initialValue: TextConstants.number,
                textFieldController: controller,
                selectorConfig: const SelectorConfig(
                    selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET),
                inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 15.h,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: TextConstants.phoneNumber,
                    prefixText: "+90 ",
                    prefixStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: ColorConstants.customGreyColor,
                        fontSize: 19.sp),
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: ColorConstants.customGreyColor,
                        fontSize: 16sp)),
```

[image]